# Bundle React/Express App for production

Tags: reactjs, express, production

My app is built with "create-react-app" and also Express.js as back-end.
How should I set up for the app for production?

Here is my user.js file from Express:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(['Hello World'])
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have "Proxy" setup in the package.json file in the React folder.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

"create-react-app" has the command for build:

```
npm run build
```

Is my app bundled for production if I just run "npm run build" in the react folder or I have to setup something in my Express files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Express acts as both your API and your application server, at a basic level you'd need to setup Express to load the `index.html` of the React application when no other API routes are caught. You would do this by using `sendFile()` along with Node's `path`, registering a "catch-all" route **after** all your other API endpoints, in the main file for your Express application.

```
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use('*', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

The path within `sendFile()` needs to point to the location of the `index.html` of the React client/frontend applicaiton. Exactly what goes into `sendFile()` entirely depends on the structure of your project. If for exampple you have the React application in a folder called `client` which has a `build` folder generated by **create-react-app** `npm run build`, the `sendFile()` would look like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));

// API route
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use('*', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

The `*` in `app.use()` such as `app.use('*', function (request, response));` means effectively all HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, etc). If you do NOT put this **after** your API routes/paths, it will prevent your React client application from making calls to the API as it will catch all requests, order is very important.

Then you simply build the React application then run the Express application.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Glad to help! Hopefully that makes sense overall what you'd need to do. The exact path in `sendFile` will depend on your project structure, which can really be anything you need.

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));`

`app.get('*', function(request, response) {
   response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
 });`I have added these two scripts in the main js file of Express, how can I test if it works?

Comment: Sure, that could work. Node's `path` has a number of methods for building path to input into `sendFile()`. `resolve()` is definitely an option, `join()` could also work. That snippet assumes that there is folder `client` at the same level as the main Express application file.

Comment: Hi, I tried to deploy to Heroku, but when I open the app, I got the error message: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/client/build/index.html', my client folder is at the same level as the main express js file, and I checked in the terminal, the "index.html" does exist in my client/build folder.

Comment: You ran `npm run build` and confirmed that `index.html` was generated by **create-react-app** prior to deploying? Also did this work locally before deploying? If not, this may be an issue with the path provided to `sendFile()`. Try `path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html')` instead.