# How to join a react app and an express app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react app with these directories :

```
-node_modules
-public
-src
```

when I run it ( `npm start`) it will be started ! 
On the other hand I have some `nodejs database config file` and `server.js` that I don't know where to put them.

Moreover I want to know How can I start both apps together and generally how to merge these two apps ?

I'm new to both of these apps BTW. Thanks.

Comment: Simply type "node express react" on google, and you will find tons of tutorials

Comment: https://github.com/shabyWoks/Expensify/blob/master/server/server.js

Comment: I did it before but cause I'm new I can't get how it works !

Comment: This may help with the routing portion of Express running both server/client https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260684/bundle-react-express-app-for-production/50260959#50260959

Comment: So you mean the react and the node both should be run individually ? @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thank you I think I'm going to be clarified .

Comment: It comes down to a couple key things: 1) Express loading the index.html generated by building the react application, including the path 2) Specifying in the correct order loading of express router endpoints

Comment: The thing in simple way is express is looking for static website and we provide the location of static web to express and express serves it. Yes for serving static website your react app must be compiled and bundled.in first hand

Comment: @ATF I know this way currently, to run both individually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the concept you are trying to understand is about two applications. The first one is called **backend** (`server.js`). The second one is the **frontend** (react app). Usually, you will run them separately (check [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0)). Let's suppose:

- Backend will start on port 5000 and serve an API.
- Frontend will serve pages (HTML + Javascript) and might run on port 3000

So, you need to open two terminals (or prompt on windows) and start 2 process:

**Terminal 1 - Backend**

```
node server.js
```

**Terminal 2 - Frontend**

```
yarn dev
```

In this case, you can make HTTP requests directly to your API (backend) calling the backend. For example: http://localhost:5000/api/something

If you hit http://localhost:3000 you should see your web page loaded by index.html file and all react application.

The frontend is just the user interface running on client's browser. So it has to make requests to the backend to actually save and load data (where the database resides).

It's also possible to serve the frontend files using your backend but it seems that the concept you need right now is the separation of frontend and backend.

Comment: Exactly this is what I wanted to figure out .Let me go through these and inform you about the results. Thank you

Comment: A development [proxy](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) with create-react-app can be used to execute calls against the server during development. This would simulate a production build being served by the same server, otherwise different addresses would need to be used development/production for API calls.