# Node.js server overwritten entire DOM with React.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

What I am trying to do: I am trying to practice MERN structure, so I wanted to set up a node.js server and react front-end first.

However, what happened is that when the server gets fired, the entire DOM got overwrite, why is that?

server.js is a simple node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Listening on port 3000`));

// create a GET route
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'I MADE IT' });
});
```

React.js is my front-end:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './img/nav-logo.png';
import Product1 from './img/manage.png';
import Product2 from './img/deliver.png';
import Product3 from './img/market.png';
import Service from './service.js'
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state={
      items: [{
          desc:"Manage",
          price: 5000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"Deliver",
          price: 2000,
          purchased: false,
        },
        {
          desc:"Market",
          price: 4000,
          purchased: false,
        }
      ],
      data:null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("here")
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.express }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/test');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
  };

  handleClick(desc){
    const newItems = this.state.items.slice()
    this.printItems(newItems)
    for(var item of newItems){
      if(item.desc === desc){
        item.purchased = !item.purchased
      }
    }
    this.printItems(newItems)

    this.setState({
      items: newItems
    })
  }

  printItems(items){
    console.log(items[0].purchased + "  " + items[1].purchased + " " + items[2].purchased)
  }

  render()  {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Shopping Center</h1>
        </header>
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.state.data}   //<------------trying to render the data here
        </div>
        <Service url={Product1} desc="Manage" alt="MA" purchased={this.state.items[0].purchased} thisClick={ (desc) => this.handleClick("Manage")} />
        <Service url={Product2} desc="Deliver" alt="DE" purchased={this.state.items[1].purchased} thisClick={ (desc) => this.handleClick("Deliver")}/>
        <Service url={Product3} desc="Market" alt="MR" purchased={this.state.items[2].purchased} thisClick={ (desc) => this.handleClick("Market")}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Without my node.js running, i can render my react just fine. 
However, once I do `npm server.js`. localhost:3000 will no longer work. So i treid `localhost:3000/test`, and the entire HTML became the string "{ express: 'I MADE IT' }"

My index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I want to render the message as part of my regular React DOM, but somehow the node server overwritten my entire front-end.

Additionally, i got an error message in console state the following:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at App._callee$ (App.js:42)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:296)
    at Generator.prototype.(:3000/anonymous function) [as next] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31252:21)
    at step (App.css?9a66:26)
    at App.css?9a66:26
```

The line of code that I located is the `componentDidMount()` method

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

Comment: It looks like you still need to serve your static app from express https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html . Or if you intend to serve your static content from a separate server, you'd need to configure them to work together.

Comment: @WillCain I did tried to serve my static page using app.use(express.static('src')). It is still the same. I am new to all of these things, how do I configure it? I first started with my react front-end and then google the tutorial of connect node and react, so i just simply put node.js in the server directory, maybe there is more i need to do?

Comment: Are you using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) for the React application?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky yes

Comment: Where is your static page and the express route to serve it? It should just contain the react root elem and bundle file.

Comment: Are you fetching the json fromwhere express is serving it? `fetch('http://localhost:3000/test')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **development**, given you are using create-react-app for your React application, you can use a [development proxy](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) to run both Express and React on separate ports. Any `fetch()` requests will be redirected to the specified proxy path/port in `package.json`. This will allow you take advantage of development tools for each platform.

1. Change the Express server port to anything other than `3000`. For example `app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Listening on port 3001'));` This is so create-react-app can run on `3000` and Express can run on `3001`.
2. Added the following line to the React application's `package.json` to enable a proxy, `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`. A fetch request to `/api/test` will be redirect to `http://localhost:3001/api/test`.

For **production**, given you would want both applications to run on the same port:

1. Set up static resource loading for the server using [static()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) method.
2. Added logic to server to redirect all requests that do not match you "API" paths, to load the `index.html` of the production built `npm run build` React application using [sendFile()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile). This will allow to use routing within the React application.

Here is what that could look like at a basic level, with the create-react-app `build` folder generated from `npm run build` command is placed into path `/public/build`:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build')));

// API route
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'I MADE IT' });
});

// catch-all route
app.use('*', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

React `fetch()`:

```
// ...
const response = await fetch('/api/test'); // this matches the path specified on server, before the catch all route
const body = await response.json();
// ...
```

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260684/bundle-react-express-app-for-production/50260959#50260959) as it was a similar issue.

**Update:** - Steps to create simple Express + React development environment:

1. Create Express application using [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). Run command `npx express-generator react-express`
2. Navigate into created project. Run command `cd react-express`.
3. Run command `npm install`. Then delete directory `public`.
4. Create React application using `create-react-app`. Run command `npx create-react-app public`.
5. Install `concurrently`. Run command `npm install concurrently --save-dev`.
6. Edit `app.js` at the base of project created by `express-generator`. Add the following lines starting at line 25. This is to expose and endpoint at `/api/test` and provide a "catch-all" route to load `index.html` generated by `npm run build`.

```

```
app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'I MADE IT' });
});

app.use('*', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

```

7. Edit `/bin/www` line 15 to change port from 3000 to 3001. `var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001');`
8. Edit `package.json` created by create-react-app at `/build/package.json`. Add the following line `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`.
9. At the base `package.json` located at the root of the project, created by express-generator, add the following line to srcipts: `"dev": "concurrently \"node ./bin/www\" \"cd public && npm start\""`
10. Run command `npm run dev` from the base of the project. This will load both the server (Express) and client (React) and will proxy calls, in this example `/api/test` on port `3000` will be directed to the server port running at `3001`.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I did tried that since it was part of the tutorial. However, when I put it in the package.json and do npm update,  it says :`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /test from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).`

Comment: Which `package.json` did you add that proxy item to? It needs to be added to the one create from `create-react-app`, not the Express one. Also when that happens are you running both the server AND the react app? As in did you open a terminal and do `npm start` or similar for the express server, then also run `npm start` for the react application? Can you hit the endpoint at `/3000/api/test` then also run react at `3000`.

Comment: I updated my answer, there is only one package.json in my project

Comment: No, i only did `npm start` for my react application and `node server.js` for my server.js

Comment: Can you use two different `package.json` in development? One at the level of the `server.js` then one at the level of the react app created with `create-react-app`? This solution described in the answer it based on two `package.json`. You would only use the server `package.json` in production.

Comment: OK it has been populated now. I first run npm start and then do node.server.js and then refreshed my page. It worked. However, it still says could not proxy request. so i have no idea how everythign works, because it just worked

Comment: it is my personal project for practice, so it is just development, there isn;t nay sort of deployment

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain steps to creating a simple environment for Express + React. Thanks!