# why do all CRUD examples have 2 servers running - can i just one instance? (mongodb, vue.js, node.js, express, mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js

As the title asks - do I need to run two services to run a single Vue.js application connecting to MongoDB? Each example i've found has a "server" or "api" that connects to MONGODB. Isn't this possible to run in a single node instance?

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely use a single node instance to run both client (Vue) as well the server (Node/Express/MongoDB). The following answer is for React + Express, but you can use the same syntax to load the index.html for your Vue project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521509/node-js-server-overwritten-entire-dom-with-react-js/52521984#52521984

Comment: As someone who has largely contributed in making a SaaS application with Node + Vue for frontend and Express + Mongodb for the back. The choice we made is mostly because we wanted to isolate the two applications, as there is no need to make on giant monster when two separate applications can do the job, even better. All they need is to communicate via the API. It's like refactoring, if you will, but for servers

Comment: Samayo has the best answer. And I get it now - keep the API open so that other apps can access that data if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like concurrently to run both instances at the same time. I prefer running them seperately for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script to start both node server and front-end in reactjs, for example in the `package.json`, you can write something like:

```
  "script" : {
    "dev": "node server.js && npm run start"
  }
```